# How to Style RadioButton

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, radio-button

I have the following Style from Blend that I have adjusted so that the radio button and text should always remain black. What I cannot seem to get though is ensuring the ellipse surrounding the RadioButton dot always remains black?

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}"/>-->
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource CustomAccentColor}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                            <!--<Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>-->
                            <!--<Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>-->
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Black" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at your template I see multiple things missing, but for your specific question I'll have to assume you're referring to the "CheckBackground" Ellipse which you have bound to the template dependency of "Background" for your `Fill` and "BorderBrush" for your `Stroke`, which you don't actually set anywhere.

So you'll start by adding that. Right above your `<Setter Property="Template">` you'll put;

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
```

Except, your "CheckMark" is also black, so I would see that as confusing to a user since there's no contrast...

You'll also want to look at your "Pressed" VisualState wherein you have a Storyboard that will change the fill of your "CheckBackground" to "CustomAccentColor" as a `StaticResource`

So effectively on the pressed state it will change it to whatever that CustomAccentColor color resource is. You could just pull that animation out to avoid that.

You'll probably want to go add some defaults for good measure for everything else in there that you have bound to the template the same way we just did for your Background.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Turns out I only needed the `BorderBrush` setter.